# Add custom button in cart page to add a particular product in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Trying to add a custom button in the cart page. If the button is clicked particular product should add and cart page should refresh with ajax load. I used below code but it is refreshing the page without updating cart prices.

```
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'customizing_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
    function customizing_cart_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data']; // Get the WC_Product Object

        if ( $value = $product->get_meta('pro_price_extra_info') ) {
            $product_name .= '<a class="gt_price" href="example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=250">Get this price</a>';
        }
        return $product_name;
    }
```

Please help me with the code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested your code and it worked as you mentioned. All you need is to add a line to recalculate cart totals: "WC()->cart->calculate_totals();"

Based on your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'customizing_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function customizing_cart_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data']; // Get the WC_Product Object

    if ( $value = $product->get_meta('pro_price_extra_info') ) {
        $product_name .= '<a class="gt_price" href="example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=250">Get this price</a>';
    }

    WC()->cart->calculate_totals();

    return $product_name;
}
```

For a better position for your button you may try this ([image: example.png]):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() {
      echo '<button class="de-button-admin de-button-anim-4"><a href="example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=250" style="color:white">Get Your Discounted Product!</a></button>';
}
```

Cart Page Hooks: *https://www.tychesoftwares.com/woocommerce-cart-page-hooks-visual-guide-with-code-examples/*

I hope it works. Have a good day.